# python map/reduce: emit multiple keys values from single map lambda

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is there a canonical way to emit multiple keys from a single item in the input sequence so that they form a continuous sequence and I don't need to use a `reduce(...)` just to flatten the sequence?

e.g. if I wanted to expand each digit in a series of numbers into individual numbers in a sequence

```
[1,12,123,1234,12345] => [1,1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5]
```

then I'd write some python that looked a bit like this:

```
somedata = [1,12,123,1234,12345]

listified = map(lambda x:[int(c) for c in str(x)], somedata)
flattened = reduce(lambda x,y: x+y,listified,[])
```

but would prefer not to have to call the `flattened = reduce(...)` if there was a neater (or maybe more efficient) way to express this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`map(func, *iterables)` will always call `func` as many times as the length of the shortest iterable (assuming no Exception is raised). Functions always return a single object.  So `list(map(func, *iterables))` will always have the same length as the shortest iterable.

Thus `list(map(lambda x:[int(c) for c in str(x)], somedata))` will always have the same length as `somedata`. There is no way around that.

If the desired result (e.g. `[1,1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5]`) has more items than the input (e.g. `[1,12,123,1234,12345]`) then something other than `map` must be used to produce it.

You could, for example, use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) to flatten 2 levels of nesting:

```
In [31]: import itertools as IT

In [32]: somedata = [1,12,123,1234,12345]

In [33]: list(map(int, IT.chain.from_iterable(map(str, somedata))))
Out[33]: [1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

or, to flatten a list of lists, `sum(..., [])` suffices:

```
In [44]: sum(map(lambda x:[int(c) for c in str(x)], somedata), [])
Out[44]: [1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

but note that this is much slower than using `IT.chain.from_iterable` (see below).

---

Here is a benchmark (using [IPython](https://ipython.org/)'s `%timeit`) testing the various methods on a list of 10,000 integers from 0 to a million:

```
In [4]: import random
In [8]: import functools
In [49]: somedata = [random.randint(0, 10**6) for i in range(10**4)]

In [50]: %timeit list(map(int, IT.chain.from_iterable(map(str, somedata))))
100 loops, best of 3: 9.35 ms per loop

In [13]: %timeit [int(i) for i in list(''.join(str(somedata)[1:-1].replace(', ','')))]
100 loops, best of 3: 12.2 ms per loop

In [52]: %timeit [int(j) for i in somedata for j in str(i)]
100 loops, best of 3: 12.3 ms per loop

In [51]: %timeit sum(map(lambda x:[int(c) for c in str(x)], somedata), [])
1 loop, best of 3: 869 ms per loop

In [9]: %timeit listified = map(lambda x:[int(c) for c in str(x)], somedata); functools.reduce(lambda x,y: x+y,listified,[])
1 loop, best of 3: 871 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

Got two ideas, one with list comprehentions:

```
print [int(j) for i in somedata for j in list(str(i)) ]
```

Something new (from comments), string is already iterable, so it would be:

```
print [int(j) for i in somedata for j in str(i) ]
```

second with opertations on strings and list comprehentions:

```
print [int(i) for i in list(''.join(str(somedata)[1:-1].replace(', ','')))]
```

output for both:

```
[1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: you don't need to call `list` on `str`. `str(i)` is already iterable.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how the transformation goes:

1. Convert every item (int) to a string: `12 -> '12'`
2. Convert every item (str) to a list of string: `'12' -> ['1', '2']`
3. Flatten every item (list of str): `['1', '2'] -> '1', '2'`
4. Convert every item (str) to an int: `'1' -> 1`

We can use [Pyterator](https://github.com/remykarem/pyterator) for this:

```
from pyterator import iterate

(
    iterate([1, 12, 123, 1234, 12345])
    .flat_map(lambda x: list(str(x)))  # Steps 1-3
    .map(int)  # Step 4
    .to_list()
)
```